# Calendar and facebook events and birthdays

Tags: sync, calendar, facebook

I'm using the native calendar in my Android 2.2. I'm also using [Simple Calendar Widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.anod.calendar&feature=search_result) but I don't think it has anything to do with my problem.

A few weeks ago everything was perfect. I had synced 3 calendars from the same gmail account and the calendar of my facebook account. So I could see the events in gmail's calendars, facebook's events and facebook's birthdays. Now, for some reason, facebook's birthdays dissapeared.

How can I do to get them back?

I read about exporting facebook calendar, but this way if after importing it in my calendar I add a friend in facebook, it's birthday wont appear, right?

Thanks!

Comment: this happened to me too (i'm pretty sure it's because i flashed a different rom ;) ) but an easy fix to get them back would be great! +1!

Comment: I'm using the stock rom, not even rooted my phone =/

Comment: Is it possible that Facebook changed their API?

Comment: I have no idea.. How could I check? (If its possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you have the calendar selected: go to `Settings -> Accounts and Sync -> [your Facebook account]` and make sure `Sync calendar` is selected. On some phones there might be a builtin Facebook sync which only takes care of the names, so if there is no `Sync Calendar` option, go to `Add account` and see if you have Facebook under `Integrated contact accounts` and `More accounts`. If so, add the one from `More accounts` and check `Sync Calendar`.

Edit: The problem can be fixed by removing and readding both sync accounts, waiting for the phone to remove them in between.

Comment: This is something that I've noticed and forgot to explain in my question. It seems to be twice my facebook account. There is one which only has "Contacts" and the other has both "Contacts" and "Calendar", the three checks are checked.

Comment: Yep, that's expected, one account is from Android and one is from the facebook app. Now that I looked at my calendar closer I found out that the birthdays are not synced through the calendar but from the contacts and from there to your own calendar on the device. Check that you have synced all your friends from Facebook and that the local calendar (called My Calendar) is not hidden.

Comment: My facebook contacts are actually synced and "My Calendar" isn't hidden :/

Comment: Can you see people's birthdays in your contacts' details?

Comment: No =(.. But I don't know if they were before.. Why could this be?

Comment: At least on my phone they are, and they show up in the calendar. Try removing both Facebook sync profiles and wait for the phone to sync them out, then add them again. I remember this worked once back when I was using Eclair.

Comment: Yey!! You save me!! I was forgetting every bodies birthday!! Please add this last comment to the answer so it can be easy to find to anybody who's having the same problem